# how to scale a polar plotted sphere up to a different radius? python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So i need to scale up the size of a sphere i plotted with polar coordinates, but I am unsure if Im doing it correctly in a  way that scales properly.

```
#og code
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.00, 3.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
r = 0.05
u, v = np.mgrid[0:2 * np.pi:30j, 0:np.pi:20j]
x = np.cos(u) * np.sin(v)
y = np.sin(u) * np.sin(v)
z = np.cos(v)
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap=plt.cm.YlGnBu_r)
plt.show()
#no matter what I change r to its always .5 by .5 units on a plot. I want it to be a radius of 50.
```

[first sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSvZI.png)
I then tried this and it returns a sphere the size I want, but I am unsure if the z coordinate is scaling the same rate as the rest because it doesn't look as spherical.

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10.00, 40.50]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = False
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.axes.set_xlim3d(left=-100, right=100) 
ax.axes.set_ylim3d(bottom=-100, top=100) 
ax.axes.set_zlim3d(bottom=-100, top=100) 
    
r = 50
u, v = np.mgrid[0:2 * np.pi:300j, 0:np.pi:300j]
x = 100*(np.cos(u) * np.sin(v))
y = 100*(np.sin(u) * np.sin(v))
z = 100*(np.cos(v))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride= 5, cstride = 5, cmap=plt.cm.YlGnBu_r)
plt.show()```
[second sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOGaX.png)


I tried to just add more points to plot and scaling them by multiplying by 100. not sure if spherical or tripping.
````

Comment: The variable `r` is completely useless in the code above; you'll want to use `set_aspect`, or `set_box_aspect`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ax.set_box_aspect()` to make sure all the axes are scaling at the same rate (aspect ratio along X, Y, and Z axis). [See the corresponding doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_box_aspect.html)

You can either pass hard-coded values or do it dynamically by retrieving the total range of `x`, `y`, and `z` values with the `np.ptp()` function.

```
[...]

# Hard coded values would be (200, 200, 200)
ax.set_box_aspect((np.ptp(x), np.ptp(y), np.ptp(z))

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride= 5, cstride = 5, cmap=plt.cm.YlGnBu_r)
plt.show()
```

This should give you the following figure
[image]

---

Regarding the radius, you're not using the `r` variable you define. Scalling `x`, `y` and `z` with `r` should work:

```py
# Keep same box aspect as previous figure to demonstrate the scaling effect
ax.set_box_aspect((200, 200, 200))  

x = r*(np.cos(u) * np.sin(v))
y = r*(np.sin(u) * np.sin(v))
z = r*(np.cos(v))
```

Here, `r=50` will generate the following figure:

[image]